# SQL Server - query optimization for highly skewed data distributions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, statistics, query-performance

I am trying to optimize a query which looks similar to this:

```
select top(1)
    t1.Table1ID,
    t1.Column1,
    t1....
    ....
    t2.Table2ID,
    t2....
    ....
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    c....
from BigTable1 t1
join BigTable2 t2
    on t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID
join Customer c
    on t2.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
join Table4 t4
    on t4.Table4ID = t2.Table4ID
join Table5 t5
    on t5.Table5ID = t1.Table5ID
join Table6 t6
    on t6.Table6ID = t5.Table6ID
where 
    t4.Column1 = @p1
    and t1.Column1 = @p2
    and t3.FirstName = @FirstName
    and t3.LastName = @LastName
    and t6.Column1 = @p5
    and (@p6 is null or t2.Column6 = @p6)
order by t2.Table2ID desc
option(recompile);
```

BigTable1, BigTable2, Customer - are big transactional table (hundreds millions of rows), Table4,Table5,Table6 are relativly static and small lookup tables.
The problem is that data in those big tables has pretty skewed distribution and because of that very often this query performs very poorly (estimated number of rows in execution plan are very different from the actual). Updating statistics on those big tables does not help (200 steps in histogram are not enough to cover all the skews in data distribution). For example, in Customer table there are a few (FirstName, LastName) combinations that correspond to about 500k records.

I see 2 options to improve performance of such queries:

1. Split this query into smaller ones and saving intermidiate results
   into temporary tables. With this approach of materializing
   intermidiate results into temporary tables we can give the optimizer
   a better opportunity  for cardinality estimations, but we add a
   substantial additiobal load on tempdb (cause this query is executed
   rather frequently, up to several times a second). And another
   drawback is that it is not faster for all parameter values, it
   appears to be significantly better for atypical parameter values
   (when the original query can take minutes, this takes just few
   seconds), but for parameters that correspond to a more o less unique
   (or infrequent) rows the approach with temp tables is slower.
2. Create filtered statistics for the spike values, for example for
   Customer table it would look like this:

   ```
   declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'', @i int, @N int;
   select top (1000)
   identity(int,1,1) as id,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   count(*) as cnt
   into #FL
   from Customer
   where 
   FirstName is not null 
   and LastName is not null
   group by
   FirstName,
   LastName
   order by cnt desc;

   set @N = @@ROWCOUNT;
   set @i = 1;

   while @i <= @N
   begin
       select @sql = 'CREATE STATISTICS Customer_FN_LN_' + cast(id as varchar(10)) + ' ON dbo.Customer(CustomerID) WHERE FirstName = ''' + FirstName + ''' AND LastName = ''' + LastName + ''' WITH FULLSCAN, NORECOMPUTE'
   from #FL
   where id = @i;
   exec sp_executesql @sql;
   set @i = @i + 1;
   end;
   ```

So if we create this filtered stats for those 3 big tables and re-create those stats, lets say, every week, we should be OK with row estimations in the original query.

From my previous experience I usually used approach with temp tables, but in this case it looks like the approach with filtered statistics is more attractive. I haven't use it in production yet though and I am curious what could be the drawbacks.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any other approaches to help optimizer deal with highly skewed data distributions?
2. What are the drawbacks of manually created and handled filtered statistics in the 2nd approach?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2008 R2. The difficulty here is that predicates filter records from 3 big tables that needs to be joined, so I can't just filter records in 1 table and get that 1 row from CTE. TOP 1 should be applied after joins are made and filters applied...

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Are there any other approaches to help optimizer deal with highly skewed data distributions?

Filtered statistics and breaking the query up using intermediate temporary tables (correctly!) are the main options, but you could also consider how an indexed view might be used to help. Properly implemented, an indexed view should have approximately the same impact as an extra nonclustered index on the base table(s).

Using `WITH (NOEXPAND)` instead of relying on automatic matching (Enterprise Edition only) will allow the optimizer to create and use statistics on the indexed view as well.

More generally, if you are able to identify the 'safe' or 'unsafe' values ahead of time, you could consider a hybrid approach (including dynamic SQL) as detailed in [Building High Performance Stored Procedures](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/) by Kimberly L. Tripp.

You could also consider multiple separate procedures optimized for different cases, using the appropriate approach in each, including hints like `OPTIMIZE FOR`.

Finally, you have plan guides and/or forced plans via Query Store (where available).

> 2. What are the drawbacks of manually created and handled filtered statistics in the 2nd approach?

Mainly issues around the filtered statistics not being updated as frequently as one might hope. You can workaround this by refreshing these statistics manually.

You're already recompiling, so that should address the use of filtered statistics with parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried an approach with materialized view and with it query performance is just excellent, execution times are consistent within 20 milliseconds which is a huge improvement. Performance degradation to data modifications seems quite tolerant as well (in my case). However I do not think we will be able to use this solution in production because of downtime it requires. Unfortunately, it is not possible to create a clustered index on a view with (ONLINE=ON). And creating a clustered index on a view joining several huge tables actually takes quite a while, in my case it was about half an hour. And furthermore, if we already have an indexed view, but need to alter underlying table, we have to drop the view and re-create it, and here we go back to the problem of originally creating a clustered index on a view and hence downtime again. 
Nevertheless, using an index view seems like the best performing solution here if the downtime is not an issue, so I think I should provide the solution here (it is of course not the exact queries I am using, but it gives an idea).

```
-- indexed view:
create view vBigView with schemabinding
as
select
    t2.Table2ID,
    t2.Table1ID,
    t2.CustomerID,
    t1.Column1,
    t2.Table4ID,
    t5.Table5ID,
    t5.Table6ID.
    t2.Column6,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
from BigTable1 t1
join BigTable2 t2
    on t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID
join Customer c
    on t2.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
join Table5 t5
    on t5.Table5ID = t1.Table5ID
go
create unique clustered index UQ_vBigView on vBigView(
    Table4ID,
    Column1,
    Table6ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Column6,
    Table2ID
) with (sort_in_tempdb = on, online = on, maxdop = 4); -- this what I was hoping to do, unfortunately, ONLINE option does not work for clustered indexes on views, so this will throw an error!
go

-- modified query
declare
    @Table4ID tinyint,
    @Table6ID tinyint;

set @Table4ID = (select Table4ID from Table4 where Column1 = @p1); -- Column1 is unique
set @Table6ID = (select Table6ID from Table6 where Column1 = @p5); -- Column1 is unique

:with cte as(
select top (1)
    Table2ID,
    Table1ID,
    CustomerID,
    Column1,
    Table4ID,
    Table5ID,
    Table6ID.
    Column6,
    FirstName,
    LastName
from vBigView with(noexpand)
where 
    Table4ID = @Table4ID
    and Column1 = @p2
    and Table6ID = @Table6ID
    and FirstName = @FirstName
    and LastName = @LastName
    and (@p6 is null or Column6 = @p6)
order by Table2ID desc
)
select
    t.Table1ID,
    t.Column1,
    t....
    ....
    t.Table2ID,
    t2....
    ....
    t.FirstName,
    t.LastName,
    c....
from cte t
join BigTable2 t2
    on t2.Table2ID = t.Table2ID
join Customer c
    on c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
join Table4 t4
    on t4.Table4ID = t.Table4ID
join Table5 t5
    on t5.Table5ID = t.Table5ID
join Table6 t6
    on t6.Table6ID = t5.Table6ID
option(recompile);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was reading your question I immediately thought about filtered statistics. The problem is that they can't be used if the query is parametrized unless you hint a recompile.

Check this nice article from Erik Darling: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/filtered-statistics-follow/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this query DOES have a recompile hint to avoid parameter sniffing issues (for the case of stored procedures) and "optimize for unknown" behavior for cases when being called as an ad-hoc.

Comment: Are you sure about recompiling a query that runs several times a second?

Comment: I do realize that recompiling this query can potentially be very expensive in terms of CPU usage. However, I do not see any other better solutions, unfortunately. Query hints is not an option since the variance of data and optimal execution plans is quite significant. If I could classify the cases depending on the values of input parameters, I would probably try using hints or plan guides, but I do not see how this classification could be achieved.

Comment: And this query is in production (with recompile hint) for quite some time already, and currently the issue is in its bad performance, not increased CPU usage because of excessive recompilation.